# does google calculate minimum device hardware requirement for an app? or it doesn't? if yes how?

Tags: android, mobile, device, hardware, require

Reason to ask this:
i would like to know what precautions / steps should be taken to make my app less and less resource hungry (processor / RAM) and keep my APK size lowest.

we develop apps for android version 7 and above.
in an old device (mobile) our app was not visible on google market (now called play store). this device was having very less internal memory and (my guess) very low RAM too. (i guess this because at that time device specifications weren't available easily on net too).
i would like to know whether google runs a testing process for every app.
if YES, then how does google do it.
Do they calculates only size of the APK and hide the app visibility on devices with less than this app's size of internal space? (not remaining memory but less by manufacturing) AND / OR do they process the app to calculate required RAM in device? etc.

Answer (score 0):

They don't.  What they do is look at the minimum SDK value in your apk and the hardware features that your manifest says you require, and won't show you to any devices that don't match those.  But there are no RAM, storage, or CPU power checks.

As an aside-  if you're really supporting down to 7 you're likely making your life harder than it needs to be.  Accord to Google less than .1% of phones that use the Play store are below version 10.  Only 2.8% are below version 15.  There's no advantage to supporting v7, 8, or 9 and really isn't worth it for 10 unless you have a very specific market in poor countries.